# retrieve an top level domain from an url using java

Tags: java

i need to retrieve an top level domain from the url means 
ex

```
http://www.google.com
```

this can be attained by

```
url.getHost();
```

but the thing is in case i have some sub domain with url

http://example.google.com

it extracts `example.google.com` i need to extract the `google.com` alone is there is any way to extract it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the second level domain of an URL (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923815/get-the-second-level-domain-of-an-url-java)

Comment: The TOP-Level domain of `example.google.com` and `google.com` is `com`. `google.com` is second level domain. The most righteous `.`-part is always the top-level, followed by second-level and so on.

Comment: be careful, there are other url schemes in use; for example, `google.co.uk`

Comment: yes i am aware of it ..the thing is i need to extract the exact domain name

Answer (score 6):

With google guava (uses public suffixes)

```
final InternetDomainName topPrivateDomain = InternetDomainName.from(uriHost).topPrivateDomain();
topPrivateDomain.name();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the java library at http://sourceforge.net/projects/publicsuffix/ 
That might help since you need all known domain suffixes and I think that jar just do that.