# Determine current domain character length

Tags: php, strlen, parse-url

I am parsing domains and running into a problem handling subdomains. If the domain is http://www.google.co.uk, I want to obtain the length of `google` which is 6.

I am using `parse_url()` to return the host in this case www.google.co.uk like so.

```php
$url    = 'http://www.google.co.uk';    
$info   = parse_url($url);    
// remove www. and return google.co.uk
$new    = str_replace('www.','',$info['host']); 
$pieces = explode(".", $new); 
$len    = strlen($pieces[0]); // returns character length of google = 6
echo $len;
```

My code doesn't work if the domain contains a subdomain like http://test.google.co.uk: it returns a length of 4; I expect it to return a length of 6.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, in the case of http://test.google.co.uk, what would you expect the length to be?

Comment: I only want to return the length of the domain not any sub domain. If there is a sub domain like test.google.co.uk then the length would equal 4 as the $pieces[0] would take the first section being 'test' and not google.

Comment: Are you saying that in the case of http://test.google.co.uk, you would expect the length to be 6?

Comment: I would like it to return 6 yes, but because of the sub domain it gives the wrong strlen() that I am after.

Comment: You won't be able to do this without a list containing all TLDs. It is impossible to determine if in `x.y.z` x or y is the domain. imagine `google.co.uk` vs `google.com`.

Comment: Yeah this is my issue, would you know of a way to do this.  I guess all TDLs will have to be added to an array and checked against the domain.

Comment: might be a time to reconsider strategy -- what is the overall goal/purpose leading to this implementation route?

Comment: If the TDL exists in array remove it from the url to give test.google then explode . to check if value is empty or nothing

Comment: the thing is -- TLDs are not constant over time, and the list is long. does one include multi-byte TLDs? how often to update list?

Comment: if you see http://www.woorank.com/en/www/google.com and go to the usability section I am trying to achieve something like this.

Comment: perhaps when evaluating the domain could compare with other entries in your database and then group those who appear to be related. trying to determine a single/isolated instance will be challenging due to the number and variancy of TLDs.

Answer (score 0):

Output is correct. when input is `http://test.google.co.uk` value of `parse_url('http://test.google.co.uk')['host']` is `http://test.google.co.uk`. When you will exploce this string on dot first element of array will be `test` and its length is 4.

To get `google` instead of `test` you need to replace subdomain with nothing as you did in your first example or take the second element in exploded string. E.g:

```
$url    = 'http://test.google.co.uk';    
$info   = parse_url($url);    
$pieces = explode(".", $info['host']); 
$len    = strlen($pieces[1]); // returns character length of google = 6
echo $len;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not other way than collect and hardcode all known public 2-nd level zones (like `co.u`k, `com.ua`, `co.tw` and so on) and filter them in your code. Be aware to detect `test.example.ua` as `test` becouse both `example.com.ua` and `example.ua` are valid domains (which is not a case with `uk` zone).

Your code may look like this:

```
function mainDomainLength($fullDomain) {
    //$fullDomain = 'DOMAIN.co.uk';
    $zones = array('uk' => array('co'), 'ua' => array('com', 'org'), ...);
    $domainArray = explode('.', $fullDomain);
    if (count($domain) > 2 && isset($zones[$domain[count($domain)-1]])) {
        if (isset($zones[$domain[count($domain)-1]][$domain[count($domain)-2]])) {
            return strlen($domain[count($domain)-3]);
        }
    } else if (count($domain) > 1) {
        return strlen($domain[1]);
    } else {
        return strlen($domain[0]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** By the way! Look at [Get the second level domain of an URL (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923815/get-the-second-level-domain-of-an-url-java). As I can understand there is the answer you need (and url to [special domains collection](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) collected be Mozilla).