# errors when using Guava to get the private domain name

Tags: ant, dns, guava

I am using `guava-18.0` and `java1.6`

Given codes below:

```
String host = null;
host = new URI(this.domain).getHost();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(host);
        if(m.find()){
            InternetDomainName domainName = InternetDomainName.from(host);
            this.domain = domainName.topPrivateDomain().name();
            System.out.println(this.domain);
        }
        else
            this.domain = host;
```

When running ant to build, it gives such error message:

```
[javac] symbol  : method name()
[javac] location: class com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName
[javac]                             this.domain = domainName.topPrivateDomain().name();
[javac]                                                                        ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 1 error
```

the method `topPrivateDomain` returns a `InternetDomainName` object and it do has a method called `name()`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`InternetDomainName`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html) does not have a `name()` method. It did up until 15.0, but it was removed in 16.0. Use `toString()`.