# Get the pay the level domain from a URL String

Tags: java, url

How to extract the pay level domain from a URL, is there any java library which automatically does this ?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923815/get-the-second-level-domain-of-an-url-java) help?

Comment: @jrook, that's about second level domain, I need the Pay Level Domain

Comment: I think the answer to that question covers that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked I didn't find any lib and I ended up using this regex:

```
private static final Pattern URL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "(?:^|[\\W])((ht|f)tp(s?):\\/\\/|www\\.)"
                + "(([\\w\\-]+\\.){1,}?([\\w\\-.~]+\\/?)*"
                + "[\\p{Alnum}.,%_=?&#\\-+()\\[\\]\\*$~@!:/{};']*)",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Guava's [InternetDomainName](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.java) might be used to compose it out of the individual elements though.

Example usage:

> For example, for the domain name `mail.google.com`, this method returns the list `["mail", "google", "com"]`

```
ImmutableList<String> parts = InternetDomainName.from("mail.google.com").parts()
```

Comment: and then how do you use it ?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I believe the example you mention only split the host part and returns the parts, this is something faily easy, but based on the parts, and related to your example, how do you know that "google" is the Pay Level Domain, that's y i was asking if there is any library

Comment: because i believe to do this, one must have a record of the host on the right and continually check if it's a public or private host